# Memory optimization for returning large S3 files from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, download, large-files

I have a use case where in I need to provide a large file [size ~ 2GB] as a downloadable to a website user through spring controller. The file is originally stored in S3.

I have tried out the approach of reading the file from S3ObjectInputStream and directly writing to HttpServletResponse outputStream[using a byte array of 1 MB size].

Even though I am not bringing the file content into memory [apart from the fixed 1 MB size buffer], the used heap memory value  increased by roughly 100 MB. I have also verified that the HttpServletResponse outputStream buffer is fixed at size 9KB throughout the process.

**Used memory derived using :** Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()

1. Is there a way to figure out what actually is causing an increase in used memory?
2. Also is there a more optimised ways in terms of memory usage for write S3 file content to HttpServletResponse.

**Note**. : As S3 pre-signed URLs can be accessed by anyone within the expiry time window, they cannot be used as an alternate to the above due to data security reasons .

Code Reference:

```
    InputStream inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
    OutputStream outStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    int lengthOfBytesRead;
    while ((lengthOfBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
         outStream.write(buffer, 0, lengthOfBytesRead);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Jmap utility to get the same.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html

Comment: In this case, don't handle the file at all; instead, sign a download URL (I recommend using jets3t) and issue an HTTP redirect to it.

Comment: Did you check [Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)?

Comment: I would use Signed URLs, where the TTL is really short (e.g. 10 seconds). Your Spring controller method can pre-sign the URL, then reply with a 302 redirect to the pre-signed URL.